# How can I define a cookie path for the cookie fe_typo_user?

Tags: cookies, typo3

It is possible to set the flags HttpOnly and Secure ([Typo3 Doc](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/SecurityGuide/GuidelinesIntegrators/GlobalTypo3Options/Index.html)).

As I have several Typo3 instances in different folders of the same domain, how can I define the Path of the cookie?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the install tool to set the global configuration value for `[BE][cookieDomain]` and `[BE][cookieName]`.
The same settings exist in the categorie `[FE]]`.